# Is there a distance d on R such that the open sets wrt d are symmetric intervals?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there a distance d on $\Bbb R$ so that the open sets with respect to d are the symmetric intervals 
i.e. so that the metric topology of d is

$T(d) = \{(−a, a), [−a, a] :a ∈ R\} ∪ \{R\} ∪ \{∅\}$

Comment: What does "open sets with respect to $d$" mean?

Comment: @Elliot G the topology induced by the metric d

Comment: here are some hints :  The identity map (R,std)->(R,T(d)), T(d) the topology given in the problem, hypothetically induced by a metric d, is not continuous  because [-1,1] is open wrt T(d) but

id^{-1}([-1,1])=[-1,1] is not open in the standard topology std of R. 

A hint for this problem: in the hypothetically metric topology T(d), every nonempty open set contains 0. Is this possible for a metric topology, i.e. can one point lie in all nonempty open sets, in particular in all balls of a metric?

Answer (score 5):

No such distance exists because this metric space would not be Hausdorff (we know that all metric spaces are Hausdorff). Consider the numbers $1$ and $2$. Every symmetric interval $(-a,a)$ or $[-a,a]$ containing $2$ would also contain $1$.

Another way to see this is that if such a distance $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ did exist, then let $s=d(1,0)>0$. The metric topology says that any set of the form $$\{x\in\mathbb R:d(1,x)<t\}$$ are open for any value of $t$. So what if $t=s/2$? Could this set contain $0$?